# How to display key from value in given dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want a function which will take value from user and display the respective key of the dictionary

Ex. d={'name':'ayush','age':21,'Hobby':'cricket'}

Please enter the value : ayush
Key related to entered value is: name

Comment: and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You want a reverse dictionary. This only works if the values are unique.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for someone to do the coding for you.
Generally people will help if you show what you've already tried.

Comment: See also: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with list-comprehension:

```
[k for k, v in d.items() if v == 'ayush']
# ['name']
```